# Android WebView in Fragment user not able to navigate after tab change

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have Fragment activity that has two fragment. First one is only WebView and second one is List View.

When I run application, I can navigate inside WebView, but the problem occurs When I change tabs and only when I changed them wih setCurrentItem().

If I change fragments by clicking on tab (with mouse or on touch) everything works fine, but if I changed them programmatically (On button click I change setCurrent item) I cannot navigate inside webView again.

I checked and that WebView has current focus, but somehow I am not able to enter it and navigate inside html of that WebView.

I tried everything, but nothing works.

Comment: This is very vague, could I see the code you are using on button click?

Comment: Even if you reload your WebView html?

Comment: Yes, even after HTML reload...It's just one line on button click and it is mPager.setCurrentItem(index)....

I just found out that this is happening when I leave fragment with WebView, but only on button click (I am using remote control)...If I touch on second tab and then go back with button click everything works fine again ( I tried using FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentStatePagerAdapter and TabHost and it is the same everywhere)